# Log4j initialisation seems to be stuck in a loop

Tags: java, log4j

I am using slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5 and log4j:1.2.17 in a java application.

This is the properties file used:

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO, infoFileLogger

#INFO
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.File=test_info.log
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=test_info.log
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=test_info_%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.infoFileLogger.Threshold=INFO
```

I ran the jar by passing debug option -Dlog4j.debug.

The log4j initialisation seems to be stuck in a loop. Getting this in logs :-

```
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, infoFileLogger].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "infoFileLogger".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "infoFileLogger".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "infoFileLogger".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [10000].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [test_info.log].
log4j: Setting property [fileNamePattern] to [test_info_%d{yyyyMMdd}_%i.log.gz].
log4j: Setting property [activeFileName] to [test_info.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxIndex] to [5].
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: setFile called: test_info.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "infoFileLogger" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j: setFile called: test_info.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: setFile called: test_info.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: setFile called: test_info.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: setFile called: test_info.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
... and so on
```

Could someone help to figure out what is the issue?

Comment: Are log messages being appended to `test_info.log`?

Comment: Yes it is being appended to test_info.log. 
Actually I got the issue. I had kept the size of triggering policy too low for testing. It was rotating very fast and hence these setfile log statements was getting called each time it created a new file. It was my miss to notice it earlier. I thought there is some issue with some thread. Because in my application log as well, the latest logs which were being written were also same. Like "processing events : 100"  and so on. But that is also expected.
Thanks for the reply!